# How to format rspec to show passing on default

Tags: rspec

How do I format rspec permanently to show passing test text. 
Currently I have to type in : `$ rspec spec --format documentation` every time I run it.

I see that the documentation says to run the following for
 "You can also specify an output target (STDOUT by default) by appending a
filename to the argument:"

```
documentation:rspec.output.txt
```

However, I do not know what it means by 'specify an output target (STDOUT by default)

I just want to see text on passing tests instead of green dots without having to type `--format documentation` every time...

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a `.rspec` file in the root of your project

```
* YOUR_PROJECT
** A_SPEC_FOLDER
** ANOTHER_SPEC_FOLDER
** Gemfile
** .rspec
** spec_helper.rb
```

Then, you just have to add to your `.rspec` file

```
--format documentation
```

and run your spec.